# Apps with tabs containing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-activity

I am new to Android, and I need your help to design correctly my apps. As an image is better than 1000 words, here is what I want to do:

[image]

So I want few tabs, with each handling some fragments.
My questions are simple:

- How do I implement this? How many activities 1 for everything or 1 per tab?
- How can I implement the tabs without displaying the android menu line, only one line that I choose?
- How can I get this in full screen?

Answer (score 0):

For Full Screen:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//int flag, int mask 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
```

Comment: it is in your wish, but do simple not make many activites then it will be boring for user.

Comment: SO you would recommand having only one activity containing all tabs, fragments, etc? Thanks :)

Comment: can you use at least 3 activity all tabs.